# .sort() Method with values of different magnitude

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I've searched for an answer and can't seem to find one on SO (feel free to prove me wrong), but here goes.

I have an impossibly large list (10's of millions of values), where all the numbers are between 100 and 1500.

if we call this list A, then essentially I'm doing this:

```
A= [impossibly large list]
A.sort()
```

Then a statement to cehck out the order of everything. What I'm expecting order-wise is:

```
A = [151.14, 300, 1501.3]
```

but what I get is:

```
A = [1501.3, 151.14, 300]
```

It appears to be sorting by the first digit, followed by the next, etc.

Anyone know if this is inherent to the algorithm underneath, or if this is because of the size of my list?

Comment: You'll see that if you are actually sorting **strings**, not numbers.

Comment: And, hence, the sort is *lexicographical*.

Comment: what is the purpose of this ... sort is on average O(nlogn) ... you might not really need to sort it...

Comment: It's for a rather niche application, where the resulting list would serve as the numbers on a virtual "axis", as if you were making an extremely large graph. For the graph to make sense, numbers should be strictly increasing. It's also just a quick and dirty solution since I'm on a tight deadline and no one cares what the code looks like right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll see that if you are actually sorting **strings**, not numbers. Strings are sorted [*lexicographically*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), with `'1'` coming before `'20'` just like `'A'` comes before `'Bee'`:

```
>>> A = ['151.14', '300', '1501.3']
>>> A.sort()
>>> A
['1501.3', '151.14', '300']
```

Convert your 'numbers' to actual floating point values either by replacing all the values in `A`, or using `float` as a sort key:

```
>>> A.sort(key=float)
>>> A
['151.14', '300', '1501.3']
```

Of course, you may want to ask yourself if you really *need* your huge list to be sorted in the first place. And perhaps other structures (trees, heaps, etc.) would serve your goals better?

Comment: That works perfectly! I wasn't aware that you could pass a key argument!